# No module named 'requests' plus error with requests in terminal

Tags: python, python-requests

I continue to get the error 
No module named 'requests'
in Python. I have requests installed, but when checked with terminal there seems to be some problems. I cannot understand, can anyone help?

```
pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2862, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2669, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 93, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1632, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1622, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3395, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3183, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 33), (line:1, col:34)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2942, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 97, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'; extra '"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    self._warn_about_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 442, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 89, in check_install_conflicts
    state = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 39, in create_package_set_from_installed
    retval[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2613, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2864, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2874, in _compute_dependencies
    reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2935, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2944, in __init__
    raise RequirementParseError(str(e))
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'; extra '"
```

Comment: Does it work when you try and install other packages?

Comment: Yes. Requests were already installed, but I get the error not finding the module in python. So I updated requests as well as anaconda, that's when error in terminal started.